# Editing child in object ActionScript 3.0 in cs5 flash

Tags: actionscript-3

I have something like that:

```
btn_1.addChild(btn1_text);
btn_2.addChild(btn2_text);
btn_3.addChild(btn3_text);
addChild(btn_1);
addChild(btn_2);
addChild(btn_3);
```

It's a part of code to create buttons. I want to edit text in `btn1_text` not by using

```
btn1_text.text = ".....";
```

But using something like that:

```
btn_1.btn1_text.text = "......";
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: This is a very very special case, and nobody does that in real life. I'm having the feeling you're not telling the entire story here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`name`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#name) and [`getChildByName()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName%28%29):

```
// Create the button and its textfield
var btn_1:Sprite = new Sprite();
var btn1_text:TextField = new TextField();
btn_1.addChild(btn1_text);
addChild(btn_1);

// Add a name to the textfield
btn1_text.name = "btn1_text";

// Retrieve the textfield using its name and set its content
TextField(btn_1.getChildByName("btn1_text")).text = "...";
```